# Finding a path to the cloud for an iOS app

Tags: iphone

I may not be eligible for the services available here. I’m a non-coder/writer vim enthusiast.

I have iVim on my mobile devices. It has a command—:iexdir—for accessing external directories. I would like to be able to synchronize directories across my devices. The plug-in I’m using—wiki.vim—requires the path to the directory to be used by it to be put in my .vimrc. I thought I had found a path that would work but it turns out it is not recognized.

Perhaps in spite of :iexdir it just can’t be done. Looking for help finding a workable path, if it is at all possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apologies. From my .vimrc

“vim-markdown 
set conceallevel=2 
let g:vim_markdown_follow_anchor = 1
let g:vim_markdown_no_extensions_in_markdown = 1
let g:vim_markdown_new_list_item_indent = 0
let g:vim_markdown_folding_level = 6 
let g:vim_markdown_autowrite = 1
let g:vim_markdown_strikethrough = 1

Let g:wiki_root = '~/private/var/mobile/library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/vimfiles/wiki/'

let g:wiki_filetypes = ['md']
let g:wiki_link_extension = '.md'
let g:wiki_link_target_type = 'md' 
let g:wiki_write_on_nav = 1

Comment: The path I thought I had—~/private/var/mobile/library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/—is the correct path. I get problems only when issuing wiki.vim commands on files in directories on it. 

Otherwise I can create and save files on this path. Disappointed that I’m not going to be able to synchronize wiki.vim files.